# how to change json request to payload form

Tags: java, json

I have a json request like this:

```
{
    "record_type": "item",
    "data": [
        {
            "item_id_wms": 75985,
            "item_type": "Inventory",
            "item_code": "ITEM8080808",
            "display_name": "ITEM E888",
            "category_item": "",
            "upc_code" : 12345678,
            "base_unit": "BOX",
            "height": 12,
            "width": 13,
            "depth": 12,
            "uom_volume": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

but I hit use `request.setPayload(request.toString());` I got error like this when hitting my other service

```
Response Body : {"error" : {"code" : "SYNTAX_ERROR", "message" : "org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: c (INVOCATION_WRAPPER$sys#24)."}}
```

but if I manually use this code: I can hit my endpoint.

```
OAuthRequest requestSendToNS = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, baseUrl);
requestSendToNS.setPayload(("{\"record_type\":\"item\", \"data\": [ { \"item_id_wms\": 99920, \"item_type\": \"kit\", \"item_code\": \"ITEM808080\", \"display_name\": \"ITEM E888\", \"category_item\": \"kit\", \"upc_code\" : 12345678, \"base_unit\": \"PCS\", \"height\": 12, \"width\": 13, \"depth\": 12, \"uom_volume\": 10, \"component\" : [ { \"item_id_component\":\"ITMIDAS0000000007\", \"quantity_component\": 18, \"unit_id_component\":\"PCS\" }, { \"item_id_component\":\"ITMIDAS0000000001\", \"quantity_component\": 15, \"unit_id_component\":\"PCS\" } ] }, { \"item_id_wms\": 99922, \"item_type\": \"kit\", \"item_code\": \"ITEM808080\", \"display_name\": \"ITEM E888\", \"category_item\": \"kit\", \"upc_code\" : 12345678, \"base_unit\": \"PCS\", \"height\": 12, \"width\": 13, \"depth\": 12, \"uom_volume\": 10, \"component\" : [ { \"item_id_component\":\"ITMIDAS0000000007\", \"quantity_component\": 18, \"unit_id_component\":\"PCS\" }, { \"item_id_component\":\"ITMIDAS0000000001\", \"quantity_component\": 15, \"unit_id_component\":\"PCS\" } ] }, { \"item_id_wms\": 99924, \"item_type\": \"kit\", \"item_code\": \"ITEM808080\", \"display_name\": \"ITEM E888\", \"category_item\": \"kit\", \"upc_code\" : 12345678, \"base_unit\": \"PCS\", \"height\": 12, \"width\": 13, \"depth\": 12, \"uom_volume\": 10, \"component\" : [ { \"item_id_component\":\"ITMIDAS0000000007\", \"quantity_component\": 18, \"unit_id_component\":\"PCS\" }, { \"item_id_component\":\"ITMIDAS0000000001\", \"quantity_component\": 15, \"unit_id_component\":\"PCS\" } ] } ] }"));
```

How can I change my json request come in the payload format like that?

Comment: Which library or class are you using to create the request?

Comment: OAuthRequest requestSendToNS = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, baseUrl); i use this

Comment: Are you sure `request.toString()` creates a valid json format?

Comment: Have ou tried to check the value of `request.toString()`?

Comment: You should share more info. More detail you post, more help you could receive. Which library are you using? How do you send the payload? Etc... OAuthRequest is just a name which no meaning, there could be milions of OAuthRequest classes from different projects and everyone has its own functionality and different usages.